# Elastic MapReduce libjars argument to reference s3 jar files

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I'm trying to run a custom jar EMR job on Amazon and I have a reference to a lucene jar file in my jar file. I have the jar file in a lib directory on s3 and my Jar arguments look like this:

```
MyMainClass -libjars s3n://mybucket/lib/lucene-core-3.6.1.jar s3n://mybucket/myinput s3n://mybucket/myoutput
```

The job fails and I keep getting these errors:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:861)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:906)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:932)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getMapperClass(JobConf.java:959)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
>     ... 14 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     ... 21 more

It doesn't seem to find the lucene jar file... What am I missing?

Comment: Does `MyMainClass` implements the `Tool` interface? Also make sure to get the Configuration instance via `getConf()` in your run method.

Comment: I do not implement the Tool interface... is there an example of this somewhere? I'm kind of new to this hadoop stuff.

Comment: Actually, I found an example and I'm getting a different error now so I think it worked. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

If your runner class implements the Tool interface, then Hadoop will invoke `GenericOptionsParser` in the background which will pick up your `-libjars` parameter automatically.